# Why "normal" user password always prints and desn't work

Tags: python, authentication, passwords

My code in general works, but has some bugs. When you type "master" it asks you the password and after typing it generates the password for "normal" users.

About the "normal" users: generates the password, but when you type it doesn't work and generates another one.
I tried to change the location of useraccess() below usertype() and keep doing the same. Also a different one where "useraccess (user = "normal", pswd = None ")" with usertype () creating a variable like "functions = " " using it with the calling functions below the statements like "functions = masterkey ()" and "functions = passwordgenerator ()" with "return functions" at the end. The rest you can imagine ...

```
import getpass
import uuid

#generate password for normal users
def passwordgenerator(pswdlength = 5):
    random = str(uuid.uuid4().int) #convierte el uuid a un string en enteros
    random = random.replace("-", " ") #reemplaza el uuid en el "-"
    return random[0:pswdlength] #imprime la contrasenha (se reemplazara despues por una funcion que mande al user)

#create a password for the admin
def masterkey():
    masterpswd = 519 #valor del masterkey
    admpswd = getpass.getpass(prompt="Ingresa tu contrasenha: ")         
    if admpswd == "519":
        print ("youre in")
    else:
        print ("try it again")

def useraccess(user = "normal"):
    userpassword = print(passwordgenerator())
    while True:
        allpswd = getpass.getpass("Password:  ")
        if allpswd == userpassword:
            print("hi")
            break
        else:
            print("you didnt made it")
            break 

def usertype():
    user = str(input("Type of user: Normal o Master  "))
    while True:
        if user.lower() == "master":
            print(masterkey())
            break
        elif user.lower() == "normal":
            print(useraccess())
            break

#calling functions
usertype()
useraccess()
```

I expect that dont double print the generated passwords and the "normal" user password to work when you write it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of unneded `print()`. If you remove them, the program will work as expected. Remember that `print()` does not return anything, so any assignment such `x = print(whatever)` will result in `x` equal to `None`.

`userpassword = print(passwordgenerator())`. print call not needed. It is masking the return value as explained above. Just do:

```
userpassword = passwordgenerator()
print(userpassword)
```

`print(masterkey())` and `print(masterkey())`. print calls again not needed. They are just printing `None`, as both functions do not return anything. Just call the functions without `print()`.

> About normal users: generates the password, but when you type it doesn't work and reprint another password after that.

This is due to the fact that you call again `useraccess()` after `usertype()`. Remove it, and call `usertype()` only.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now is working. I was thinking about the unnecessary print, but I didn't know that they can return None and why. Now it became clearer to me.

Comment: If you find the answer useful, please [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)